# Hide logout button while logged out

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Say I have a logout navlink in my navbar that I want hidden while the user is logged out and obviously there while logged in? I've tried to change the state onClick with no luck and no luck on searching for any useful answers so I have reverted it back to just always being there. How could I go about this.

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried.

Comment: use application state, `this.isAuthenticated?

Comment: Do you use redux ?

Comment: No redux is being used, but not out of the question. Just started learning about it

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to key some sort of a value/key in your browser's local-storage and render it depending on the value in the local-storage. When you log out change that value.